# getting filename in variable & echoing them

Tags: windows, batch-file

In a directory I want to get each filename into a variable and then echo the variable to the screen.

```
REM Example 1 works but does not put filename in variable
FOR %%F in (*.*) do (
    echo %%F
)

REM Example 2 here I try to put the filename into a variable named x but when I run it it only displays the filename of 

FOR %%F in (*.*) do (
    set x=%%F
    echo %x%
)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: ...one of a million questions about [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use delayed expansion like so

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR %%F in (*.*) do ( set x=%%F & echo !x! )
```

Comment: This method is unable to properly display the name of a file when it contains exclamation marks.